# unable to read redis values if only GET is Used

Tags: java, spring, redis

In the following code snippet i am unable to read(GET) the value from redis.

```
ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("SpringContext.xml");

   User user = new User(); // java Bean

 RegistrationBean bean = (RegistrationBean) applicationContext.getBean("RegistrationBean");

         User user = new User();
        user.setUserid("200112021");
        user.setName("name1");
        user.setAddress("adress sd");
bean.getRedisTemplate().opsForHash().put("A12", user.hashCode(),user);


User x = (User)bean.getRedisTemplate().opsForHash().get("A12",user.hashCode());
System.out.println(x.getName());
```

The above code runs only when PUT and GET are used simultaneously, but if do not use PUT and use only GET for a specific record then i get NULL values pls suggest ?

Thanks
vijay

Comment: Is there a UI framework for JSP which can integrate with Spring Data Redis. If so pls suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is resolved....

I used the Spring MVC API. The following is the code snippet

public String addcustomer(@ModelAttribute("customer")customerVO customer,  ModelMap model) {  // gettting the customer data from UI

```
    model.addAttribute("QuestionName", customer.getQuestionName());
    model.addAttribute("comments", customer.getComments());
    model.addAttribute("pollID", customer.getPollID());
    model.addAttribute("answer", customer.getAnswers());

    ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("servletDispatcher-servlet.xml");


  CustomerRepository customerRepository = (CustomerRepository) applicationContext.getBean("customerrepository");

    customerRepository.put(customer);
    System.out.println(" Step 1 output : " + customerRepository.getObjects());
```